# ReactiveX observable that uses another observable

Tags: angular.js, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am trying to write an Angular service that will wrap the regular Http service and automatically make authentication calls if Bearer token is not available or invalid.

Here's an illustration of a regular GET call made via the service:

```
this.httpWithAutomagicAuth
    .get("http://localhost:5001/books")
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            self.data = data;
        }
    );
```

And here's my very sloppy implementation for such service. Obviously, I'm not using the right ReactiveX idioms in the code.

**As you can easily notice I am trying to build an observable (Observable.create) that is using another observable returned by this.login(). I am sure there is a better way of chaining/nesting observable for this scenario.**

Please, suggest improvements that will make code:

- terse
- easy to read and understand

  ```
  @Injectable()
  export class HttpWebApiAuthService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  // ...

  public get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
      // TODO this code is for test purpose only (basically, it required to enforce the jwtToken retrieval branch execution)
      // this.clearJwtToken();

      if (!this.getJwtToken()) {
          return Observable.create(
              (result: Observer<Response>) => {
                  this.login()
                      .map(res => res.json())
                      .subscribe(
                          data => {
                              this.saveJwtToken(data.id_token);

                              this.executeGet(url, options)
                                  .subscribe(authenticationResult => {
                                      result.next(authenticationResult);
                                  });
                          },
                          error => { console.error("Authentication error", error); },
                          () => { console.info("Authentication complete"); }
                      );
                  },
                  error => { console.error("OBSERVABLE error: ", error); },
                  () => { console.info("OBSERVABLE complete");
              }
          );
      } else {
          return this.executeGet(url, options);
      }
  }

  private login() : Observable<Response> {
      const authBody =
          {
              "client_id": "...",
              "username": "...",
              "password": "...",
              // ...
          };
      const headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

      return this.http.post("https://AUTH_URL", JSON.stringify(authBody), { headers: headers });
  }

  // ...

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `flatMap` to achieve what I wanted:

```
public get(url: string): Observable<Response> {
  return this
    .login()
    .flatMap(token_id => this._http.get(url));  // token_id can be used here
}

public login(): Observable<string> {
  const authBody =
      {
          "client_id": "...",
          "username": "...",
          "password": "...",
          // ...
      };
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

  return this._http
    .post('AUTH_URL', authBody)
    .map(response => response.json().token_id);
}
```